# Woocommerce hook in 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty' set to false

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm triying to hook into "woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty" https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1467
and set it to false to show empty categories, but if i add this to my function file:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', false ) ;
```

Nothing comes up in the page, just blank (no header nothing).

What is right way to do this?

I know that i could delete this lines in  wc-template-functions

```
if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', false ) ) {
        $product_categories = wp_list_filter( $product_categories, array( 'count' => 0 ), 'NOT' );
}
```

And it will solve the issue and show empty categories, but i want to do it with a hook not with editing woo core files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', 'so_28060317', 10, 1 );
function so_28060317 ( $show_empty ) {
    $show_empty  =  true;

    return $show_empty;
}
```

[`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) is what you use when you're creating an extensible theme or plugin.

[`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) is what you use when you're extending a theme or plugin that has a corresponding `apply_filters` call.

The filter you're looking to use is in `includes/wc-template-functions.php` on line 1467 (as of WooCommerce 2.2.10)

I wrote a full guide [here](https://majemedia.com/woocommerce-how-to-show-empty-categories/)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as a one-liner in your theme or plugin functions:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty", "__return_true");
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_true

Answer (score 0):

Lee Powers' answer is correct except you need to return false, not true if you want to show empty categories.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', '__return_false');
```

Sorry for separate answer, I tried to answer via comment but don't have enough reputation.